# upgrading the v7 appcompat support library to v23.1.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I have upgraded the v7 appcompat support library to `v23.1.0` from `v18.0.0` and i see issues with various styles such as `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar`, `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.Spinner` and `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.` I am using `compileSdkVersion 23`, `targetSdkVersion 23` and `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"`.

Error is something like this: `Error:(1728, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.Spinner'.`

My question would be is there any api documentation that would suggest what these styles would look like with the new versions? Right now i am stuck since I do not have any idea on what these should look like with v23.1.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar` should be working correctly
`@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.Spinner` -> `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner`

---

The best way to find out what style you can use is to:

1. Use the built-in (in Android Studio) auto-complete feature

[image: auto-complete]

2. `CMD+click` (or `ctrl+click` if you're using windows) on any (**valid**) style

[image: cmd+click]

and peek into the `values.xml` to find a proper style for your needs

[image]

Comment: Sure. It helped. Thanks!